# The 'publish on' date must be in the future

Tags: rules

Is there a way to set the content to be published on future time instead of future date. I get the message "The 'publish on' date must be in the future" when trying to set publish date to today but late at night.

Comment: Bala, I think your edit to this question changes the question's meaning, and I'm not sure I agree with it.  I don't think the original author said that "Whenever the node is trying to publish during night time i get this message." I think they simply said they get this when they schedule it for later in the day TODAY.

Comment: @Boriana that's correct, as soon as we put the date and time, and try to save the content it comes up with that message.

Answer (score 1):

Under

> admin/config/content/scheduler

you can set your date format. What have you set here? Has the date format included time formatting?

The publish time has to be added after the date (that is today).

Comment: yes I have configured the date and time to d-M-Y H:i:s, I and yes I did add time after the date

Comment: Can you provide us with a non-working example? Another source for the error could be another time-zone set up (Server, your drupal default time zone and user-specific time-zones).

Comment: for some weird reasons the embargo is now working fine. Just tested now when trying to recreate the problem. Thanks

Comment: Fine. You may try to test towards the date that isn't working and see if there are discrepancies with your time-zones. (Another common mistake is to set the publish date to 0:00h and expect this to be midnight that day... which isn't ;o)